# .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues still paste formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I try to run a macro which will make multiple sheets based on values in certain column - data in new sheets should be values only, not formulas. However my code somehow still paste formulas instead of values. Could you please tell me where is the error in my code?

Ps. please don't mind leftovers from message box, I'm still messing around with it

```
Sub SplitToWorksheets()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ColHead As String
Dim ColHeadCell As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Long 'row index on Fan Data sheet
Dim Lrow As Integer 'row index on individual destination sheet
Dim Dsheet As Worksheet 'destination worksheet
Dim Fsheet As Worksheet 'fan data worksheet (assumed active)
Again:
ColHead = "Columnname"
If ColHead = "" Then Exit Sub
Set ColHeadCell = Rows(3).Find(ColHead, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If ColHeadCell Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Heading not found in row 1"
GoTo Again
End If
Set Fsheet = ActiveSheet
iCol = ColHeadCell.Column
'loop through values in selected column
For iRow = 4 To Fsheet.Cells(65536, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
If Not SheetExists(CStr(Fsheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value)) Then
Set Dsheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
Dsheet.Name = CStr(Fsheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value)
Fsheet.Rows(3).Copy
With Dsheet.Range("A2")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
Fsheet.Range("A2:FN2").Copy
With Dsheet.Range("A1")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
Fsheet.Rows(1).Copy
With Dsheet.Range("A1")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
End With
Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 27.5
Else
Set Dsheet = Worksheets(CStr(Fsheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value))
End If
Lrow = Dsheet.Cells(65536, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
Fsheet.Rows(iRow).Copy Destination:=Dsheet.Rows(Lrow + 1)
Next iRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Fsheet.Rows(iRow).Copy Destination:=Dsheet.Rows(Lrow + 1)` - were you expecting this to paste values?

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that part - how can I make it to paste values instead of formulas?

Comment: The exact same way you're doing elsewhere. `PasteValues` should be a separate step.

Comment: What BigBen said, but also you could do `Dsheet.Rows(Lrow + 1).Value = Fsheet.Rows(iRow).Value`

Comment: Yeah this line was the case, thank you so much for help